# Clustering with DBSCAN is surprisingly slow

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am experimenting with clustering and I am surprised how slow it seems to be. I have produced a random graph with 30 communities each containing 30 nodes. Nodes in a communities have a 90% chance of being connected and edges between nodes not in the same community have a 10% chance of being connected.  I am measuring the similarly between two nodes as the [Jaccard similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) between their sets of neighbors.

This toy example spends about 15 seconds just on the dbscan part and this increases very rapidly if I increase the number of nodes. As there are only 900 nodes in total this seems very slow.

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import dbscan
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

#Define the Jaccard distance. Following example for clustering with Levenshtein distance from from http://scikit-learn.org/stable/faq.html
def jaccard_distance(x,y):
    return 1 - len(neighbors[x].intersection(neighbors[y]))/len(neighbors[x].union(neighbors[y]))

def jaccard_metric(x,y):
    i, j = int(x[0]), int(y[0])     # extract indices
    return jaccard_distance(i, j)

#Simulate a planted partition graph. The simplest form of community detection benchmark.
num_communities = 30
size_of_communities = 30
print "planted partition"
G = nx.planted_partition_graph(num_communities, size_of_communities, 0.9, 0.1,seed=42)

#Make a hash table of sets of neighbors for each node.
neighbors={}
for n in G:
    for nbr in G[n]:
        if not (n in neighbors):
            neighbors[n] = set()
        neighbors[n].add(nbr)

print "Made data"

X= np.arange(len(G)).reshape(-1,1)

t = time.time()
db = dbscan(X, metric = jaccard_metric, eps=0.85, min_samples=2)
print db

print "Clustering took ", time.time()-t, "seconds"
```

> How can I make this more scalable to larger numbers of nodes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here a solution that speeds up the DBSCAN call about 1890-fold on my machine:

```
# the following code should be added to the question's code (it uses G and db)

import igraph

# use igraph to calculate Jaccard distances quickly
edges = zip(*nx.to_edgelist(G))
G1 = igraph.Graph(len(G), zip(*edges[:2]))
D = 1 - np.array(G1.similarity_jaccard(loops=False))

# DBSCAN is much faster with metric='precomputed'
t = time.time()
db1 = dbscan(D, metric='precomputed', eps=0.85, min_samples=2)
print "clustering took %.5f seconds" %(time.time()-t)

assert np.array_equal(db, db1)
```

Here the output:

```
...
Clustering took  8.41049790382 seconds
clustering took 0.00445 seconds
```

Comment: This is a really great answer. Thank you!

Comment: Depending on what number of nodes you like to scale to, further tricks may be required.  E.g., the memory to hold `D` may become a problem, which sparse matrices (accepted by [DBSCAN](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html)) may help with.

Comment: That sounds great. I will definitely look into it as I do want to use larger graphs.